# Why VASP calculates the elastic constant for another trigonal space group?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, physical-properties-of-materials, polymers, elasticity

Please, help me to understand the problem. I calculated the elastic constants for the beta PHB (Space group P3221 (154)), it has to show the reduced elastic constant matrix (six), however, `VASP` calculated me 7 constants for the trigonal symmetry point group 3 (I used `IBRION=6`, `ISIF =3`, `NFREE=2` and `POMIT =0.015`). I really don't have any idea why maybe anyone has the same problem? I attached my `POSCAR` file of beta PHB below. Thank you in advance!

My `iNCAR`:

```
PREC    = Accurate
ENCUT   = 520
EDIFF   = 1e-6
IBRION  = 6
NFREE   = 2
ISIF    = 3
ISYM    = 2
POTIM   = 0.03
NSW     = 1
ISMEAR  = 0
SIGMA   = 0.1
ALGO    = Normal
IALGO   = 48
ISTART  = 0
LPLANE  = .TRUE.
LCHARG  = .FALSE.
LWAVE   = .FALSE.
```

My `POSCAR` :

```
betaPHB                                 
   1.00000000000000     
     9.8451449602803063   -0.0000000000135996    0.0000000000000000
    -4.9225724801283759    8.5261456395240547    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    4.7787902416829580
   C    O    H 
    12     6    18
Direct
  0.4473348233320940  0.0098405107170283  0.6760647908616504
 -0.0098405007170275  0.4374943136150696  0.3427314468616541
  0.5625056563849357  0.5526651466679172  0.0093981238616490
  0.3366105966273176  0.9865190814127033  0.9194381388236403
  0.0134809465872924  0.3500915452146104  0.5861048248236396
  0.6499084547853901  0.6633893733726792  0.2527714818236401
  0.3529941479661700  0.9450538256463469  0.4095367091398003
  0.0549461813536503  0.4079403223198091  0.0762033731398051
  0.5920596476801820  0.6470058220338273  0.7428700221398052
  0.2595370428953800  0.0867656901155276  0.8956333322755682
  0.9132342808844670  0.1727713537798490  0.5623000192755711
  0.8272286462201509  0.7404629871046158  0.2289666612755733
  0.4289822938404916  0.0307095082417344  0.1799468951856006
  0.9692905017582659  0.3982727945987476  0.8466135811855999
  0.6017272054012526  0.5710177061595080  0.5132802081855978
  0.2217465615454436  0.8287633736506727  0.4032896651433156
  0.1712366113493296  0.3929831728947801  0.0699563291433201
  0.6070168271052196  0.7782534534545532  0.7366229781433196
  0.5360727369674801  0.1339552292303300  0.6484256472182774
  0.8660447627696694  0.4021175007371532  0.3150923032182820
  0.5978824992628468  0.4639272630325195  0.9817589602182746
  0.5084713038609513  0.9437122479440904  0.7170050087321858
  0.0562877230559037  0.5647590559168535  0.3836716647321826
  0.4352409730831384  0.4915286961390490  0.0503383407321812
  0.2476974100787215  0.8620678575193049  0.9347039188362016
  0.1379321714807079  0.3856295665594249  0.6013706048362009
  0.6143704334405750  0.7523025749212737  0.2680372618362011
  0.1875979130778683  0.0556088716245804  0.7051825810070412
  0.9443911253754161  0.1319890374532876  0.3718492370070449
  0.8680109625467131  0.8124020869221317  0.0385159130070434
  0.1827452577710241  0.0681168022337463  0.0754234213029564
  0.9318831687662399  0.1146284565372744  0.7420901073029557
  0.8853715284627206  0.8172547562289704  0.4087567643029560
  0.3478634616025427  0.2118811433998376  0.8853498234737521
  0.7881188266001669  0.1359823182027122  0.5520165094737514
  0.8640177107972945  0.6521365383974570  0.2186831514737536
```

Comment: May you can format your INCAR and POSCAR into the code block.

Comment: Please put your INCAR and POSCAR into a `code` block as Jack suggested.

Comment: Your POSCAR is little tilted in xy direction. If you have calculated elastic contants, you can see that two elastic constants are nearby same with some difference. Just verify your space group using spglib python library (best use vaspkit).

Comment: I have check your POSCAR, it's space group is 145. It is mainly due to relaxation due large cell using ISIF3 lost little symmetry

Comment: pranav kumar, thank you, I think my fixed-pressure optimization with ISIF=3 and then the fixed-volume optimization with the ISIF=2 led to the space group number changing. Could you please give me advice, is it better to use ISIF=7 during the optimizaton and after that for the elastic constan calculation? I'm really new in this.

Comment: You can try but in elastic constant you might get little different result as vasp minima lie in space group 145. You can also find elastic using energy-strain relationship with using algorithm of vasp.

Comment: pranav kumar, I found out, that my structure initialy has the 145 space group, I used the structure from this paper Macromolecules 2019, 52, 2995−3009. However, now I don't understand why it is so...Sorry for bothering you, but maybe you know, or it is really the problem in the reported data of Macromolecules 2019, 52, 2995−3009?

Comment: Related:https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/problem-related-to-the-calculation-of-elastic-constant-with-vasp5-4-4

Comment: Thank you all, I understand my mistake. I reduced the space group at the first step, because the beta PHB has the chains which are positioned at the same lattice site at the statistical probability of 50%. I am really new in polymer crystallograthy and elastic constants calculation, therefore, I am a bit confused, what to do...

Answer (score 3):

Elastic constants can be calculated using two approach, one with Energy-strain relationship and another with stress-strain relationship. The key ingredient in above two methods is energy or stress at particular mode of distortion. For example in cubic crystal which have 3 fold symmetry about body diagonal need three independent elastic parameters to define second-order elastic constants. `VASP` algorithm  `IBRION=6` also do the same. Some time problem of not getting elastic constants correctly depends on many parameters. Specially with large systems which consists of many number of atoms along with different atomic numbers, full volume relaxation results in difference between input and output structure. For example you can try relaxation of 4 atom aluminum unit cell and re-relaxed its supercell again with same K-space density and kinetic energy cutoff. You may get minor difference in output configuration with `ISIF=3`(full volume and position relaxation). You can also simply check your input file symmetry using python `spglib` library or just use `vaspkit`. The question arises if there is minor change in symmetry, can we get same number of elastic constants as it should be. The answer is check your elastic constants values, is two elastic constants are apart by small amount, you can always say those are equal. Other way to calculate elastic constants without `VASP` and`IBRION=6` is just distort crystal manually based on symmetry and do only position relaxation(`ISIF=2`) and then fit energy and distorsion by second order polynomial.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Recently we have also developed a python based tool to calculate second order elastic constants from strain-energy method.
https://github.com/prnvrvs/elastic_vasp